# как я могу объединить все запросы через веб-сокеты на yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, сервер, websocket

Я установил [walkor/Workerman](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman). Я хочу чтобы все запросы прошли через веб-сокет. Подскажите как это внедрить. в yii2 basic. или уже есть готовые решение? не нашел в интернете

Comment: Зачем ВСЕ запросы отправлять через веб-сокет?

Comment: @ArchDemon Чтобы ускорит время процесса запросов

Comment: Не ускорите. Точнее сказать вы ускоряете не то

Comment: @ArchDemon значит это не вариант да? что можете предложить?